# Reading NFC Tags available in iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone

As we know that iPhone6 or iPhone6+ will have NFC chip using for ApplePay and iOS 8 does not provide any SDK for reading/detecting RFID tags.Is any SDK available in iOS 10 helps us to reading/detecting RFID tags?

Comment: No, nothing has changed in iOS 10 with regard to NFC